# Why wont my if statement work, in my stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Alright so i am not even sure if this is possible
I have a q_00 and q_01 and q_02 which are all in my stored procedure.
then on the bottom i have 3 select statements
that select a certain catagory for example Sales,Net Sales and INS sales

What i want to be able to do is if the user types exec (name of my sp) (sales) (and a year which is the @yearparameter) it will run the sales select statement

If they type Exec (name of my SP) netsales (@Yeartoget) it will show the net sales is this possible or do i need multiple stored procedures

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[casof]
 @YearToGet int,
 @mode VARCHAR(20)
 as
;
with
q_00 as (
select
      DIVISION
    , SDESCR
    , DYYYY
    , sum(APRICE)        as asofSales 
    , sum(PARTY)         as asofPAX        
    , sum(NetAmount)     as asofNetSales        
    , sum(InsAmount)     as asofInsSales        
    , sum(CancelRevenue) as asofCXSales        
    , sum(OtherAmount)   as asofOtherSales        
    , sum(CXVALUE)       as asofCXValue  
from dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
where Booked <= CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate()), DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)))
  and DYYYY = @YearToGet
group by DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY 
),
q_01 as (
select     
      DIVISION 
    , SDESCR
    , DYYYY 
    , sum(APRICE)        as YESales 
    , sum(PARTY)         as YEPAX 
    , sum(NetAmount)     as YENetSales
    , sum(InsAmount)     as YEInsSales 
    , sum(CancelRevenue) as YECXSales 
    , sum(OtherAmount)   as YEOtherSales
    , sum(CXVALUE)       as YECXValue
from  dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
where DYYYY=@YearToGet
group by DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY 
),
q_02 as (
select
      DIVISION
    , SDESCR
    , DYYYY
    , sum(APRICE)        as CurrentSales 
    , sum(PARTY)         as CurrentPAX        
    , sum(NetAmount)     as CurrentNetSales        
    , sum(InsAmount)     as CurrentInsSales        
    , sum(CancelRevenue) as CurrentCXSales        
    , sum(OtherAmount)   as CurrentOtherSales        
    , sum(CXVALUE)       as CurrentCXValue  
from dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
where Booked <= CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, (year( getdate() )) - Year(getdate()), DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0)))
  and DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))
group by DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY 
)

IF @mode = 'sales'
select
      a.DIVISION 
    , a.SDESCR
    , a.DYYYY
    , asofSales 
    , asofPAX        
    , YESales 
    , YEPAX 
    , CurrentSales 
    , CurrentPAX 
    , asofsales/ ISNULL(NULLIF(yesales,0),1) as percentsales
    , asofpax/yepax as percentpax
    ,currentsales/ISNULL(NULLIF((asofsales/ISNULL(NULLIF(yesales,0),1)),0),1) as projectedsales
    ,currentpax/ISNULL(NULLIF((asofpax/ISNULL(NULLIF(yepax,0),1)),0),1) as projectedpax
from q_00 as a
join q_01 as b on (b.DIVISION = a.DIVISION and b.SDESCR = a.SDESCR and b.DYYYY = a.DYYYY) 
join q_02 as c on (b.DIVISION = c.DIVISION and b.SDESCR = c.SDESCR)
order by a.DIVISION, a.SDESCR, a.DYYYY ;


else if @mode= 'netsales'

select
      a.DIVISION 
    , a.SDESCR
    , a.DYYYY
    , asofPAX        
    , asofNetSales        
    , YEPAX 
    , YENetSales
    , CurrentPAX 
    , CurrentNetSales
    , asofnetsales/ ISNULL(NULLIF(yenetsales,0),1) as percentnetsales
    , asofpax/yepax as percentpax


,currentnetsales/ISNULL(NULLIF((asofnetsales/ISNULL(NULLIF(yenetsales,0),1)),0),1) as projectednetsales
,currentpax/ISNULL(NULLIF((asofpax/ISNULL(NULLIF(yepax,0),1)),0),1) as projectedpax

from q_00 as a
join q_01 as b on (b.DIVISION = a.DIVISION and b.SDESCR = a.SDESCR and b.DYYYY = a.DYYYY) 
join q_02 as c on (b.DIVISION = c.DIVISION and b.SDESCR = c.SDESCR)
order by a.DIVISION, a.SDESCR, a.DYYYY ;

 ELSE IF @mode = 'inssales'

select
      a.DIVISION 
    , a.SDESCR
    , a.DYYYY
    , asofPAX     
    , asofInsSales        
    , YEPAX 
    , YEInsSales 
    , CurrentPAX 
    , CurrentInsSales 
    , asofinssales/ ISNULL(NULLIF(yeinssales,0),1) as percentsales
    , asofpax/yepax as percentpax
    ,currentinssales/ISNULL(NULLIF((asofinssales/ISNULL(NULLIF(yeinssales,0),1)),0),1) as projectedinssales

from q_00 as a
join q_01 as b on (b.DIVISION = a.DIVISION and b.SDESCR = a.SDESCR and b.DYYYY = a.DYYYY) 
join q_02 as c on (b.DIVISION = c.DIVISION and b.SDESCR = c.SDESCR)
order by a.DIVISION, a.SDESCR, a.DYYYY ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another parameter called say @mode and use `if @mode='sales'` to perform conditional logic.

Following your update though I'd be tempted to create two helper parameterised inline TVFs.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.AggregateBookingDetails  
(   
    @Booked datetime, 
    @YearToGet int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
select
      DIVISION
    , SDESCR
    , DYYYY
    , sum(APRICE)        as Sales 
    , sum(PARTY)         as PAX        
    , sum(NetAmount)     as NetSales        
    , sum(InsAmount)     as InsSales        
    , sum(CancelRevenue) as CXSales        
    , sum(OtherAmount)   as OtherSales        
    , sum(CXVALUE)       as CXValue  
from dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
where @Booked IS NULL OR Booked <= @Booked
  and DYYYY = @YearToGet
group by DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY 
)
```

GO

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_casof
(   
    @YearToGet int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
select       
      a.DIVISION
    , a.SDESCR
    , a.DYYYY
    , a.Sales as a_Sales
    , b.Sales as b_Sales
    , c.Sales as c_Sales
    , .... /*etc. etc*/
from dbo.AggregateBookingDetails(CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, @YearToGet - Year(getdate()), DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0))), @YearToGet) as a
join dbo.AggregateBookingDetails(NULL, @YearToGet) as b on (b.DIVISION = a.DIVISION and b.SDESCR = a.SDESCR and b.DYYYY = a.DYYYY) 
join dbo.AggregateBookingDetails(CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, (year( getdate() )) - Year(getdate()), DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 1, getdate()), 0))), year( getdate() )) as c on (b.DIVISION = c.DIVISION and b.SDESCR = c.SDESCR)
)
```

Your stored procedure conditional logic would then just need to select the desired columns from the second of these TVFs.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[casof]
@YearToGet int,
@mode VARCHAR(20)
as
IF (@mode='sales')
SELECT collist1 FROM dbo.fn_casof(@yeartoget)
ELSE
    IF (@mode='netsales')
    SELECT collist2 FROM dbo.fn_casof(@yeartoget)
    ELSE
    SELECT collist3 FROM dbo.fn_casof(@yeartoget)
```

Comment: so i would create a new parameter, but how would the value of that parameter now to select all the sales columns

Comment: You'd have to code that in. It might make sense to factor this out into different stored procs that you call from the main proc.

Comment: hmm would it be better to separate it or to have one procedure

Comment: @myheadhurts - multiple procedures.  It will be easier to maintain and more logical, especially if the scope expands

Comment: i think i want to try it in both, because i need to learn how to do it in a single procedure and in multiple

Comment: could you explain this a litte more, because in my SP i use Q_00(stands for asof) and Q_01(stands for year end) and Q_02(and for current), then the three of these supply the sales,netsales,othersales....etc in your query where am i going to get this information

Comment: o i see you are using the function to create a, b and c. but i still don't understand how to implement this exactly im sorry im a noob

Comment: The first TVF encapsulates the logic from your three CTEs these are quite repetitive with only the parameterisation changed. The second one encapsulates the logic you are using in your select statements. Again these seem quite repetitive with the same JOINS on the same CTEs but just the column list changed. So put all columns of interest into the 2nd TVF then you can just select from that. AFAIK inline TVFs will be expanded out much like views so there won't be additional work caused by defining columns that don't get selected.

Comment: so i am going to use these two functions and then pull them into a stored procedure or is the first one a function and the second a stored procedure?

Comment: thank you i will work on it now and let you know have a greate new years

Comment: even after removing the converts i get a parenthesis error this is driving me nuts

Comment: @myheadhurts - Remove the calculations from the call list to the TVF and put the results into variables then call the TVF using variables then - or update to the latest service pack for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's what you're asking, but:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prcSelector @query VARCHAR(20), @yeartoget INT
AS
        IF @query = 'sales'
                SELECT  @yeartoget
        ELSE IF @query = 'netsales'
                SELECT  'netsales'
        ELSE IF @query = 'other'
                SELECT  'other'
```

Substitute `SELECT` statements with your queries.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure casof, Line 89
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts  - Ah I see you are using it after a CTE definition - that complicates things a bit, You could use Views instead of CTEs to get around this.

Comment: Actually just noticed that you would need to use a parameterised TVFs not a View :-)

Comment: you lost me, so i cant do an if statement?

Comment: @MyHead - hold on - I'll edit my answer with a few more details in a bit!

Comment: alright thanks this is my first real stored procedure, besides the simple ones